# I have an error http status 500 - Cannot find any information on property 'email' in a bean of type 'pack1.Driver'

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I keep getting this error eventhough i already have property email in my Driver class. This is my Driver class

```
package pack1;

import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {
private String name, email, password, contact;
private char gender;


public Driver()
{
    name = "";
    email = "";
    password = "";
    contact = "";


}



public void setDriverName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDriverGender(char gender){
    this.gender=gender;
}

public void setDriverEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public void setDriverPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
}

public void setDriverContact(String contact){
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getDriverName(){
    return name;
}

public char getDriverGender(){
    return gender;
}

public String getDriverEmail(){
    return email;
}

public String getDriverPassword(){
    return password;
}

public String getDriverContact(){
    return contact;

}

public static boolean LoginDriver(String email, String password){
    boolean validate = false;


    try{
        Connection con = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select * from driver      where Email=? and Password=? ");

        ps1.setString(3, email);
        ps1.setString(4, password);
        ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
        validate = rs1.next();

        con.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return validate;

}



}
```

and this is the code for my servlet

```
package pack1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;



/**
* Servlet implementation class Servlet6
*/
public class Servlet6 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Servlet6() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        Driver driver = new Driver();

        driver.setDriverEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        driver.setDriverPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

        if(Driver.LoginDriver(request.getParameter("email"), request.getParameter("password")))
        {
            Driver dr = new Driver();
            dr.setDriverEmail(String.valueOf(request.getParameter("email")));
            dr.getDriverEmail();

            HttpSession sessionDriver = request.getSession();
            sessionDriver.setAttribute("email", dr.getDriverEmail());

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("DriverInfo.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
        else
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd3 = request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginFail.html");
            rd3.forward(request, response);

        }

    } finally {}

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

and finally this is my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="pack1.Driver"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>AIRA Carpool</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
<center><img src = "aira.jpg" class = "companySize"/></center>
    <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="main.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="Login.jsp">LOGIN</a>
            <li><a href="form.html">JOIN</a></li>
            <li><a id="find">FIND</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="Rate.html">RATE US</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <jsp:useBean id = "driver" scope = "request" class = "pack1.Driver"></jsp:useBean>


    <br><br>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <div class ="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <form  action = "Servlet6" method = "POST">
    <input type = "email" id = "email" name = "email" value="<jsp:getProperty name="driver" property="email"/>">
    <label for = "email">Email</label>
    </div></div>
    <div class ="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input type = "password" id = "password" name = "password" value="<jsp:getProperty name="driver" property="password"/>">
    <label for = "password">Password</label>
    <input type = "submit" class = "btn waves-effect waves-light" value = "Submit"/>
    </form>
    </div></div></fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

here are the list of errors if anyone is interested

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'email' in a bean of type 'pack1.Driver'
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getReadMethod(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:756)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1220)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$GetProperty.accept(Node.java:1131)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2444)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:471)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3652)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:252)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I already tried the solutions of putting property name in lowercase and i really dont understand why it cant find the property email since its clearly there. there must be something that i cant see. i really need your help. thank you in advance

Comment: Per java bean rules, your getters and setters have to be the same name as the property. (i.e. - setEmail vice setDriverEmail). There are ways around this, but since you don't actually _need_ a way around this, you should follow convention.

Comment: @rmlan oh my god that is actually all i have to do. Thank you so much sir you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

Your property is named "driverEmail" as a consequence of:

```
public void setDriverEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getDriverEmail(){
    return email;
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
```